# Can Lingo 11 work in parallel

Tags: multithreading, lingo

Can Lingo 11 work in parallel that utilizes multi-cores?
Or can Lingo work with multithreading?

Answer (score 0):

As quoted in Lingo manual: "LINGO can run multiple linear programming solvers in parallel on multi-core machines. You will need to run the LINGO|Options command, go to theLinear Solver tab, and disable the request to run the barrier solver in parallel."

Check it out @ http://www.scribd.com/Mathi3u/d/39140079-Lingo-11-Users-Manual